# Difference between GATEWAY_REQUEST_URL_ATTR and request URI

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

What is the difference between `GATEWAY_REQUEST_URL_ATTR` and request URI from `ServerWebExchange`? In some built-in filters like `ForwardPathFilter` only the URI of the request is modified but in others e.g. `RewritePathGatewayFilterFactory`, they are both changed. When creating a custom filter for changing something in the URL should I change one of these or both?